# Convex hull and number of vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $S_N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be the convex hull of a finite set of $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., $S_N := \mathrm{conv}(\{x_1, \ldots, x_N\})$, and let $V_N$ be the associated set of extreme points (vertices).
If one randomly adds an additional point (different from the previous ones), say $x_{N+1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, can it happen that $V_{N+1} \subset V_{N} \cup \{x_{N+1}\}$, where $V_{N+1}$ is the set of vertices associated to $S_{N+1} := \mathrm{conv}(S_{N} \cup \{x_{N+1}\})$?
In summary, is it true that, in adding a new point, what can only happen is that either $V_{N+1} = V_{N}$, or $V_{N+1} = V_{N} \cup \{x_{N+1}\}$, and therefore the new point does not cut-off any vertex of $S_N$?

I know the answer is trivial, but I'm not able how to work this out.

Comment: Well, you're basically asking if it's possible that either $x_{N+1}\in S_N$, or $x_{N+1}\notin S_N$, where in the latter case it will become an extreme point. Are you perhaps asking what the probability is of this event?

Comment: @bodil More or less. I'm asking whether the two conditions you identified are the only ones that can actually happen. For the moment, I'm not looking at any probability statement of that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_N\in\text{conv}(V_n)$, then $V_{N+1}=V_N$.

If $x_N\notin\text{conv}(V_n)$, then $x_N$ may eliminate from $0$ to $N-n+1$ points (worst case when it reduces the hull to a simplex).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you have any reference pointing to that result? For "in $D$ dimension", you mean for some $D \leq n$?

Comment: @GuidoLaremi: sorry, $n$ (though degeneracies are possible).

Comment: OK, now it's clear. Could you please suggest me any book or paper?

Comment: @GuidoLaremi: you don't believe the figure ?

Comment: Yes, I do believe it. Just wondering whether there is also a formal proof associated.

Comment: @GuidoLaremi: it is easy to build explicit examples.

Comment: OK, thank you. Sorry, another question. Are you sure about the upper bound $N - n + 1$? Cause if you take a simplex in $\mathbb{R}^2$ made with $N = 3$, I think one can remove at most $1$ point. Am I wrong?

Comment: @GuidoLaremi: I estimate the probability that I am off by one close to $100\%$.

Comment: @GuidoLaremi You can read "Convex Optimization" by Boyd. Basically the argument boils down to whether the newly added vertex can be expressed as a convex combination of the extreme points of $S_N$, i.e. whether there exist weights $\theta_i\geq 0$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^N\theta_i = 1$ and $x_{N+1} = \sum_{i=1}^N \theta_ix_i$. Equivalently, if the new point $x_{N+1}$ can be separated by a (hyper)plane, then it certainly is not in $S_N$, and it will become an extreme point. Note that in that case, most of the other extreme points are not guaranteed to remain such.